# textView returns null pointer when I try to restore my activity from a bundle

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, textview

I'm trying to use saved instance state methods to save the contents of a text view but it keeps returning a null pointer exception (LogCat: Attempt to Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference). The app works fine on launch, but for some reason the textView is null when the activity is destroyed and restored (IE when I rotate the screen)

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextView;

    //other fields
    public static final int MAX_SEATS = 6;
    int numSeats;
    String resultText = "0";
    static final String KEY_RESULT_STRING = "result string";
    static final String KEY_NUM_SEATS = "numberSeats";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            resultText = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_RESULT_STRING);
            numSeats = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_NUM_SEATS);
            displayResult();
        }
        //variables for widgets
        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        //next two lines display "where would you like to sit" on screen
        TextView mIntro = findViewById(R.id.intro);
        mIntro.setText(R.string.introduction);
        EditText mNumRequestedSeats = findViewById(R.id.seatAmountNumberEdit);

        Button reserve = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
        reserve.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            //EditText mNumRequestedSeats = findViewById(R.id.seatAmountNumberEdit);
            try{
                String requestedSeats = mNumRequestedSeats.getText().toString();
                numSeats = Integer.parseInt(requestedSeats);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException wrongSeat){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.wrongFormatError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                numSeats = 0;
            }
            displayResult();
        });
    }
        private void displayResult(){
            if (numSeats > 6){
                resultText = "Please dial 123-456-7890 for parties larger than 6";
            }else {
                resultText = "Thank you for your reservation.";
            }
            mTextView.setText(resultText);
        }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        savedInstanceState.putString(KEY_RESULT_STRING, resultText);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_NUM_SEATS, numSeats);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

and here is the layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/numberOfSeats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/intro"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/introduction"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/waiter_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/submit_button"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/waiter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_button"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/button_grey"
            android:text="@string/mainActivitySubmit"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/intro"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seatAmountPrompt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="130dp"
            android:text="@string/seatAmount"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/seatAmountNumberEdit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="306dp"
            android:ems="3"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seatAmountPrompt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seatAmountNumberEdit" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried initializing the textView with a default String value but it still comes back with a null pointer when I change orientation. What am I doing wrong?
Note: I know it's probably easier to use something like textFreeze in the layout XML but this is a springboard into a more complicated project so I want to learn to implement saved bundles properly.

Comment: Because you call to `displayResult()` in the `if` statement before you have initialized `mTextView`. It works when you first launched the app because `savedInstanceState` is `null`, and when you rotate the screen `savedInstanceState` no longer is null therefore it execute the code in the `if` statement.

Comment: For a quick fix just move this line `mTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);` to the top of `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#java

You are missing the `public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` function.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I finally got a chance to look over the code properly. The issue is that you have placed `findViewById()` code **after** you call `displayResult()`. The `TextView` components have not been initialized/ hooked up yet, so they're still `null`. The reason `onRestoreState()` is working is because it is being called **after** the Activity view has been created.
Relocate this code after everything else inside `onCreateView()`.

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
            resultText = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_RESULT_STRING);
            numSeats = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_NUM_SEATS);
            displayResult();
        }
```

To add to the excellent point made by @Sovathna Hong, the reason it works is because the non-overwritten method is then being called. It is important that we understand that the `onRestoreState()` is being called in both cases, it is simply being auto called when we don't explicitly override it in case of `if(savedInstanceState != null)`.

Comment: I was trying to follow methods under the section "Restore activity UI state using saved instance state" in the link you referenced (both ways should work per that documentation).  Using the onRestoreInstanceState instead worked; I'd still love to know why the "saved instance state" didn't, though.

Comment: ```onSaveInstanceState()``` is used to save the values to retain them when your Activity is destroyed, and ```onRestoreInstanceState()``` will do the actual retrieving of said values so that you may hook them up to your components again when you plan to restore your Activity. Hope this helps.

Comment: Look at the comments provided for ```onSaveInstanceState()```: __invoked when the activity may be temporarily destroyed, save the instance state here__. And ```onRestoreInstanceState()```: __This callback is called only when there is a saved instance that is previously saved by using onSaveInstanceState(). We restore some state in onCreate(), while we can optionally restore other state here, possibly usable after onStart() has completed. The savedInstanceState Bundle is same as the one used in onCreate().__

Comment: You don't need to explicitly override onRestoreInstanceState(). You can just retrieve your saved data from `savedInstanceState` if it's not null in `onCreate()`, because that where he initializes his code anyway.